# jquery validation with onblur/onfocus

Tags: jquery

I've added onfocus and onblur to my text input of a form.

```
<form id='AddCameraFormWebcam' name='' method='post' action='<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); ?>'>
    <label for="CameraName">Camera name:&nbsp;</label>
    <input id="CameraName" name="camera_name" size="24" maxlength="36" value="Enter label for camera" onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue){this.value=''; this.style.color='#000';};" onblur="if(this.value==''){this.value=this.defaultValue; this.style.color='#666';}" />
...
    <button type='submit' class='submit_camera' name='addcamera' value='Add'>Add</button>

</form>
```

This now breaks my validation I had with jquery:

```
$(".submit_camera").click(function() {
    $("#AddCameraFormWebcam").validate({
        rules: {
            camera_name: {
                required: true,
                cameravalidation: true,
                minlength: 3,
                maxlength: 32
            }
        },
        messages: {
            camera_name: {
                required: "Enter a label for your camera",
                minlength: jQuery.format("At least {0} characters required!"),
                maxlength: jQuery.format("Maximum {0} characters allowed!")
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Someone can now submit without typing anything for the camera name because `Enter label for camera` will get submitted to the server. How can I still show an error?

Comment: before calling validate inside the click event, you could try checking the input field and clear it out if it equals the default value. Or, you could also write your own custom rule for the validator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to create a custom rule (you already have a cameravalidation?):

```
var enterText =  $("#CameraName")[0].defaultValue; // "Enter label for camera";

jQuery.validator.addMethod("cameravalidation", function(value, element) {
    return value != enterText && value.length > 0;
}, "Enter a label for your camera");

$("#AddCameraFormWebcam").validate({
        rules: {
            camera_name: {
                cameravalidation: true,
                minlength: 3,
                maxlength: 32
            }
        },
        messages: {
            camera_name: {
                minlength: "At least 3 characters required!",
                maxlength: "Maximum 32 characters allowed!"
            }
        }
    });
```

A jsfiddle based on your form here: http://jsfiddle.net/bSQQx/2/

Comment: Right, already had a custom rule, added your suggestion. Thanks!